# How to programmatically embed iframe in a page

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to render a page with iframe embedded in it. My code is as follow

```
public function giveHugs() {
  return [
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => '<iframe frameborder="0" style="border: none;" width="400" height="400" src="{{ url }}"></iframe>',
    '#context' => [
      'url' => 'yahoo.com'
    ]
  ];
}
```

Some how its not rendering the iframe , rather it is embedding the drupal site it self. How can i render iframe in a page?

Comment: `yahoo.com` isn't a URI. Try `http://yahoo.com`

Answer (score 2):

Unless you provide an absolute URL, Drupal will treat it as relative. So `yahoo.com` becomes `https://example.com/yahoo.com`, which explains why you're seeing your own site embedded.

To solve, just use an absolute URL:

```
'#context' => [
  'url' => 'https://yahoo.com'
]
```